# Testing celery task

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rabbitmq, celery

I have a multi tenant system set up. Celery with RabbitMQ is set up.
I have a system which triggers an email at the pre save signal of a model.
Here is the code:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Student)
def invite_stu(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user_email = instance.email
    subject = 'dummy'
    message = ''

    html_message = 'dummy'
    from_email = my email id 
    to_list = [user_email]
    send_html_mail(subject, message, html_message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, to_list)

    # super(Employee, self).save()
    return instance
```

I am writing a test case for this:

```
class BaseSetup(TenantTestCase):
    def setup_tenant(self, tenant):
        """
        Add any additional setting to the tenant before it get saved. This is required if you have
        required fields.
        """
        user = User.objects.create(email="dummy@dummy.com", is_active=True)
        user.set_password('dummy')
        tenant.owner = user
        user.save()

    def setUp(self):
        self.sync_shared()
        tenant_model = get_tenant_model()
        app.conf.update(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
        app.conf.update(CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS=True)
        print app.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER
        test_schema_name = self.get_test_schema_name()
        test_tenant_domain_name = self.get_test_tenant_domain()
        self.tenant = tenant_model.objects.filter(schema_name=test_schema_name).first()
        self.c = TenantClient(self.tenant)

    def test_core_student_put_api(self):
        response = self.c.post('http://test.localhost:8000/login/',{'email':'admin@dummy.com','password':'dummy'})
        response_add_student=self.c.post('http://test.localhost:8000/student_admin/',{'email':'xxx@dummy.com','stu_number':'100','role':'STUDENT'},**{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION':'JWT '+response.data['token']})

        self.assertEqual(response_put_employee.status_code, 201)
```

The test is running fine and it is even taversing through the mail function. But celery isnt initiating and sending mail if I run it through tests, but will send email if I add a student through API.

Any way to work with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this. My task was a periodic task, testing in django creates a new test db during test and I found that mailer queue used to get stored in that database and celery was not able to pick up from that test database.So, i had to explicitly call the task from my test case, it looks something like this.

```
@override_settings(task_eager_propagates=True,task_always_eager=True,broker_url='memory://',backend='memory')
def test_core_student_put_api(self):
        response = response = self.c.post('http://test.localhost:8000/login/',{'email':'admin@dummy.com','password':'dummy'})
        response_add_student=self.c.post('http://test.localhost:8000/student_admin/',{'email':'xxx@dummy.com','stu_number':'100','role':'STUDENT'},**{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION':'JWT '+response.data['token']})

        self.assertTrue(project_tasks.delay())
        self.assertEqual(response_put_employee.status_code, 200)
```

I had to over ride celery settings as suggested in celery docs for test configuration.
I have explicitly called **project_tasks.delay()** with **assertTrue**. my task contains a simple send_mail() command. It is fetching right data from my signals as well.**invite_stu** signal calls send_html_mail() which adds to to the mail queue in test db and when i explicitly call my periodic task(which is a periodic task) it sends the mail.I had read somewhere that celery cant pick up periodic tasks for test cases because of temporary database issue, should do some more research on that, but for present this fixes my issue.